# Why would the RIAServices.EntityFramework NuGet Package break context class code generation?

Tags: entity-framework-5, wcf-ria-services, dbcontext

I have an existing project using RIAServices with Entity Framework. The project builds correctly and generates the AmsiWeb.g.cs file with all the context classes for my services.

I am converting my designer based entities and ObjectContext with Code First entities and DbContext.  I installed the RIAServices.EntityFramework NuGet package to the web application that contains my services. However, now when I build the AmsiWeb.g.cs file only contains the WebContext class. It doesn't contain any generated services.

I have only at this point converted a single EDMX model to Code First and DbContext and made the requisite changes to the services that use that model to inherit from DbDomainService.

I am using EF 5.0... not sure if that matters cause I'm not sure how adding a DLL to the AmsiWeb application project would break code generation.

What would cause this to no longer work and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that their needs to be a redirect for Entity Framework 5.0 (4.4.0.0 since I was using .Net 4.0) in the web.config. But, since my RIA Services were in a web application project that was not my root project the code wasn't generating.

Once I added the redirect to the web.config of the web application with the RIA services in it, the context code was correctly generated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a problem within the msbuild task that generates the proxy code (I mean the *.g.cs file). Probably it's looking for the wrong version of a entity framework. Have a look at this blog post http://mcasamento.blogspot.it/2012/10/entity-framework-5-code-first-and-wcf.html in the final part I wrote an assembly redirect statement that did the trick